# Databricks AlreadyExistsException(message:Table xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx already exists)

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

When I execute the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW baseretail.managers AS

SELECT

* 

From rawretail.rentals
```

I get the error

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: AlreadyExistsException(message:Table managers already exists)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error, because I'm using the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW baseretail.managers AS
```

Any thoughts?

I'm getting the following as part of the error message:

```
Error in SQL statement: TableAlreadyExistsException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_ALREADY_EXISTS] Cannot create table or view `retailrpt`.`managers` because it already exists.
Choose a different name, drop or replace the existing object, add the IF NOT EXISTS clause to tolerate pre-existing objects, or add the OR REFRESH clause to refresh the existing streaming table.
```

Can someone let me know how to `"add the OR REFRESH clause to refresh the existing streaming table"?` please

I should mention that there are multiple VIEWs in the notebook that needs to executed multiple times - however I don't think that would cause this issue.

when I execute the command `DESCRIBE baseretail.managers` I get
[image]

Comment: what `DESCRIBE baseretail.managers` gives you?

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt thanks again for reaching. I’m not at my desk at the moment to let you know what the outcome of DESCRIBE baseretail.managers is. But, can you let me know what your thoughts are?  And what I should be looking for?

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I have updated the question with the output from ```DESCRIBE baseretail.managers``` . I seriously think the issue concerns refreshing. I say this because if I rerun the notebook after I get the error the notebook executes without any problems.

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I entered the command ```DESCRIBE baseretail.managers``` in the cell before ```CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW baseretail.managers AS``` and I no longer get the error. Does the ```DESCRIBE``` command do something to refresh or something? In anycase I'm not getting the error after executing ```DESCRIBE baseretail.managers```.

Comment: not sure - it may depend on your specific setup, like, external metastore, etc.

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I just ran the notebook again, and the error is coming back. This is so weird because I ran the notebook the notebook a number of times before telling you it worked. And now I'm gettng the error.

Comment: I don't understand when why I get the error after executing ```CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW baseretail.managers```

Answer (score 0):

The below approach will help you achieve this.

```
%sql
USE sales_schema;
CREATE  OR  REPLACE  VIEW sales_view AS
SELECT  *
FROM sales;
```

For example, I have created a schema called **sales_Schema** and created a view called **sales_view**. Using the above query.
[image]

[image]

The error message states that you are trying to create a view or table named **managers**, but it already exists in the database.

The below query will drop the schema

```
%sql
DROP  SCHEMA  IF  EXISTS baseretail02 CASCADE;
```

And `CREATE  SCHEMA  IF  NOT  EXISTS sales_schema;`
And then you can also try the below way if you are referencing with the schema

```
%sql
CREATE  VIEW baseretail02.details02 AS
SELECT  *
FROM sales_schema.sales;
```

[image]

I have also tried various ways to **DESCRIBE** schema
The below are the steps:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dileep, thanks for reaching. Sorry for the delayed response. Are you suggesting that  I drop the database using DROP  SCHEMA  IF  EXISTS baseretail CASCADE; ? This can be quite dangerous

Comment: @Patterson No worries, I understand it would be a risky procedure to drop schema.
You can use the below query that uses
Referencing the sales schema
%sql
CREATE  VIEW baseretail02.details02 AS
SELECT  *
FROM sales_schema.sales;
try this and let me know for any blockers

Comment: thanks again for getting back. I will try your suggestion. However, without adding CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW I'm sure I will definitely get the error ```TableAlreadyExistsException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_ALREADY_EXISTS]```